# Excel :How Do I Recover A Deleted Sheet In An Excel File?

Tags: excel

I accidentally deleted Sheet2 of an Excel file and saved
the file. I tried to retrieve the information but could not
locate the deleted Sheet in the deleted folder or recycle bin.

Is there a way to retrieve this sheet? It contains a lot of
information that will take lots of time to recreate.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this website is all about programming. You might want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so in order to find out what kind of question can be asked on this site. Afterwards, I suggest that you remove this post and find a more appropriate website for this question. You might want to give [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). Yet, I am pretty confident that there is no chance you can recover the sheet unless you have some kind of sophisticated backup solution including versioning.

Comment: No, that's why when you click to delete a sheet, Excel shows the confirmation box "Data may exist in the sheet selected for deletion, to **permanently** delete the data, press Delete". Use this as a lesson in not saving after a big mistake(?!) and backing up your work.

Answer (score -1):

Go to  File > Open >

Scroll down (**Bottom of the Page**) you will see ***Recover Unsaved Workbooks***

[image]

---

excel backup every (10 minutes) by default

[image]

Comment: The OP clearly states that he / she would like to recover a sheet after the file has been saved. So, how does this post "answer" the question posted above?

Comment: Excel always save a backup even if the PC lose power and it will be there when you run Excel next Time